# Unsure how to solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equations:

$\frac{dS}{dt} = -\beta SI$ ; $\frac{dI}{dt} = \beta SI - \alpha I$

I tried solving this system by using the seperated variable method, however in order to find S I need to evaluate the integral of I and vice versa. I went on google and found something called the SI model. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything ressembling the model I have. Also, I have the following formula:

$\frac{dI}{dS} = -1 + \frac{\alpha}{\beta S}$, but I am unsure how to solve this equation as well and I'm not entirely sure what even is the point of finding a function I(S(t)) when I can't even find S(t).

Comment: You can solve the $\frac{dS}{dI}$ equation using separation of variables. A solution S(t), I(t) of your equations defines a curve in the plane by $\gamma(t) = (I(t), S(t))$ and finding S in terms of I will give you an alternative way to describe the points contained in $\gamma$ as the points where S = f(I). This is an example of something called  a plane autonomous system.

Comment: You will probably find more search results under the keyword "SIR model" or "zombie apocalypse model. The $I(S)$ curve also tells you the asymptotic values as $I(t)$ starts with a small concentration and eventually converges to zero, so the two solutions of $I(S)=0$ should be about the initial population on one side and the final $S$ population on the other side.